# The type was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Im getting the error The type 'ViewModels:StatusToBackgroundColorConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.    Why it doesnt find it if it finds WorkoutViewModel.
Any ideas.
I tried to make a folder which is called converters but it was giving the same error

[image]

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Muscles_app.Views.WorkoutPage"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Muscles_app.ViewModels"
             BackgroundColor="White"
             x:Name="Workouts">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewModels:WorkoutViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ViewModels:StatusToBackgroundColorConverter x:Key="StatusToBackgroundColorConverter" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

Comment: is the converter in the same namespace as the VM?  Note that namespace and folder structure are NOT the same thing